# Error: uninitialized constant Homebrew while running Redis

Tags: redis, homebrew

I encountered this while following this https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-mac-os/ and run `brew services start redis`:

```
Error: uninitialized constant Homebrew::Service::System
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/cmd/services.rb:61:in `services'
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:94:in `<main>'
```

I reinstalled Redis, but it's still like this.